# Fixar último elemento da lista não ordenada no rodapé

Tags: html, css

O HTML exibe um menu com altura mínima, é possível deixar o último item alinhado no rodapé do menu de modo fixo? Coloquei 5 itens antes de "todos" mas é possível que tenha menos ao ser gerado pelo banco, mas o último poderia ficar fixo no rodapé.

```css
ul.lista {
  height: 200px;
}

ul.lista li,
ul.lista li a {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.lista li a {
  padding: 2px 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
}

ul.lista li a:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista">
  <li><a href="">Link#01</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link#02</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link#03</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link#04</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link#05</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Todos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Exemplo de como visualizo o menu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia elaborar um [mcve] demonstrando o que deseja fazer?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é exatamente isso que pretendo, um norte para o exemplo, é fixar o último <LI> em height: 500px; independente da quantidade de outros <LI> e ali ficar, não sei como fazer.

Comment: Vc quer que o último LI sempre fica colado na base do container pai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa "fixar" é a última `<li>` da lista, e não o último `<a>`. Isso porque o `<a>` é filho da `<li>` e não faz, propriamente, parte da lista. Também deveria aplicar as outras propriedades nas `<li>`, e não nos `<a>`. Por exemplo, aqui:

```
ul.lista li,
ul.lista li a {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Você está resetando propriedades dos `<a>` que não existem.

Deveria ser apenas:

```
ul.lista li{
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Neste trecho também:

```
ul.lista li a {
  padding: 2px 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
}
```

Se você quer fazer um menu vertical com usando lista, quem deveria ter essas propriedades de borda e espaçamento interno eram as `<li>`, e não os `<a>`. Ficaria assim:

```
ul.lista li{
  padding: 2px 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
}
```

E enfim, para fixar a última `<li>`, como informado na outra resposta, você também deve aplicar as propriedades na última `<li>` `:last-child`, e não `a:last-child`, porque senão irá aplicar em todos os `<a>` da lista, porque todos os `<a>` são `:last-child`. Ficaria assim:

```
ul.lista li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
ul.lista {
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}
ul.lista li{
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.lista li{
  padding: 2px 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
}
ul.lista li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista">
    <li><a href="">Link#01</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link#02</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link#03</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link#04</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link#05</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Todos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Caraca, por isso que alguns estilos em last-child em outros elementos não corrigiam, agora entendi e até acertei outros detalhes do html, e funcionou perfeitamente no código a disposição do último elemento. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o valor `fixed` da propriedade `position`:

```
ul.lista li a:last-hcild{
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Essa propriedade faz com que o elemento fique fixado na tela, então ele não faz parte do fluxo da página.

Se o elemento for fazer parte do fluxo da página, é melhor utilizar o `position: absolute`.

O valor `absolute` precisa de um outro elemento na página que sirva de referência, onde você coloca o valor `relative`.

```
ul.lista {
     position: relative;
     height: 200px;
}

ul.lista li a:last-hcild{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     border-bottom: 0px;
 }
```

O `ul.lista` servira como ponto de referência para `ul.lista li a:last-hcild`. Desta forma o elemento ficará dentro da estrutura do menu, e você poderá definir onde ele irá ficar posicionado.

Comment: Então o último filho será absoluto em relação à lista e será fixado no rodapé com bottom dentro do container, na teoria é isso? Fiz a implementação de relative e absoluto e fixou legal, só usei left ao invés de right e funcionou bem.